# How to get an element in json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to get to an element:

```
 {
           "long_name" : "Santa Cruz",
           "short_name" : "Santa Cruz",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
```

from this [Google Map API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=36.9950817327496,-122.029120814363&sensor=false)

using the following code:

```
 var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var json = jsonSerialiser.Deserialize<dynamic>(this.RawResult);
```

`this.RawResult` contains the json from the Google API.  I've been trying different things but to no avail.

Help please.  Thank you!

Comment: What's the value of `json` variable after you executed `var json = jsonSerialiser.Deserialize<dynamic>(this.RawResult);` ?

Comment: @ekad it's a dictionary with two elements.  Element zero is an array of four elements and so on.

Comment: @Zuzlx: You can put break point on json variable and debug it. This will help you to identify how to access the elements in the json object.